# Typescript class with never member. Is this a bug?

Tags: typescript

To my understanding this should not be possible:

```
class UndefinedStringFactory {
    universalValue: never;
    constructor() {}
    build(): string {
        return this.universalValue;
    }
}

let x: string = new UndefinedStringFactory().build();
console.log(x); // Didn't know that undefined is of type string...
```

This works even with the `strict` compiler option (Typescript 2.7.1 and 2.8.0-dev.20180206). When I remove the empty constructor, it doesn't compile as expected.

Comment: This code is nonsense. What does a declared property of type `never` mean?

Comment: It doesn't mean to make sense. But I think it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Not a bug, but a horrible misuse of the never type, which should only be used as a function return type. Typescript does allow you to declare variables of type never, although a case can be made that it shouldn't. But that argument should probably be had in the typescript repo, not here (in a new issue maybe, I couldn't find an existing one about this).

Comment: I remember a [little discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386#issuecomment-329162989) about how much complaining the compiler should do when it encounters `never`, but maybe it does deserve its own separate issue.

Comment: According to TypeScript documentation `The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type;however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never. ` That explains why the compiler does not complain when you assign  `never` to a string. Moreover, `never` is not exactly same as `undefined`

Comment: Yes, thats perfectly fine. But, because of `--strictPropertyInitialization`, TypeScript should have checked that something was assigned to `universalValue` within the constructor (which of course is not possible, except when the constructor itself has a `never` parameter). TypeScript does actually check that when you don't specify the constructor at all. Then it doesn't compile. I think in this example no constructor and an empty constructor should be equivalent.